# HTML python, flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: html, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

so here's my create page code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/create.css')}}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Details</div>
      <div class="content">
        <form action="{{ url_for('theme')}}" method="POST">
          <div class="user-details">
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="details">Full Name</span>
              <input
                id="name"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                class="form-control"
                aria-describedby="Name"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="email">Email</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                required
                aria-describedby="Email"
                class="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="profession">Profession</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="profession"
                placeholder="Enter your profession"
                required
                class = "form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="country">Country</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="country"
                placeholder="The country you live in"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="hobby">Hobby</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="hobby"
                placeholder="What do you like?"
                required
                class="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
              <span class="Phone_no.">Youtube channel</span>
              <input
                type="text"
                name = "youtube"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your youtube channel link"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
          <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where i enter my details.
here's my python app sqlalchemy table:-

```
class details(db.Model):  
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120),  nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    profession = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    hobby = db.Column(db.String(120))
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Details %r>' % self.id
```

and i get the details entered by the user in the next page using:-

```
@app.route('/info/theme', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def theme():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        country = request.form['country']
        profession = request.form['profession']
        hobby = request.form['hobby']
        try:
            db.session.add(details(name= name,email = email,country= country, profession =profession,hobby= hobby))
            db.session.commit()
            print("Successfully added")
            print(name, email, country, profession, hobby)
            return redirect(url_for('theme'))
        except:
            return "There was an issue adding your details"
    else:
        return render_template('theme_select.html')
```

and it does register the data in my db. But now to display it i do:-

```
@app.route('/result', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def result():
    print(request.form)
    name = details.query.order_by(details.name.desc()).first()
    email = details.query.order_by(details.email.desc()).first()
    hobby = details.query.order_by(details.hobby.desc()).first()
    country = details.query.order_by(details.country.desc()).first()
    profession = details.query.order_by(details.profession.desc()).first()
    return render_template('/black_theme/index.html', name= name, email= email, profession= profession, hobby= hobby, country= country)
```

and for the html page using jinja:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Gen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='black_theme/css/style.css')}}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
</head>
{% block content %}
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href=>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://{youtube}.com">Blogs</a></li>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                <li><a href="email">Contact me</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </header>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            {% for name in details %}
            <h1>hello I'm {{details.name}}</h1>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <main>
            {%for name in details %}
            {% for email in details %}
        <p>Greetings, I am {{details.name}}. I'm a {{details.profession}} from {{details.country}}. I love {{details.hobby}}, Make sure to check out my blogs!</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

but i get nothing. PLEASE HELP!!
This is what i get:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6nb.jpg)
no texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through 'details' in your Html file, but you haven't passed 'details' from the render_template function. You don't have to use for loop here as you are not passing a dictionary or a list, instead, you can simply put {{name}} or {{profession}} or {{email}} or whatever you want inside your html file.
Instead of saying:

```
<div class="title">
    {% for name in details %}
    <h1>hello I'm {{details.name}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You can write it as:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>hello I'm {{name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

> ```
> def result():
>     print(request.form)
>     details= details.query.order_by(details.name.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.email.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.hobby.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.country.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.profession.desc()).first()
>     return render_template('/black_theme/index.html', details=details)
>
>
> <div class="title">
>            
>             <h1>hello I'm {{details.name}}</h1>
>            
>         </div>
>         <main>
>
>         <p>Greetings, I am {{details.name}}. I'm a {{details.profession}} from {{details.country}}. I love
> ```
>
> {{details.hobby}}, Make sure to check out my blogs!

Answer (score 0):

Or
use this:

> ```
> def result():
>     print(request.form)
>     details= details.query.order_by(details.name.desc()).all()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.email.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.hobby.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.country.desc()).first()
>     #details = details.query.order_by(details.profession.desc()).first()
>     return render_template('/black_theme/index.html', details=details)
> ```
>
> {{for detail in details}}
>
> ```
>             <h1>hello I'm {{detail.name}}</h1>
>            
>         </div>
>         <main>
>
>         <p>Greetings, I am {{detail.name}}. I'm a
> ```
>
> {{detail.profession}} from {{detail.country}}. I love
> {{detail.hobby}}, Make sure to check out my blogs!
>
> {{ endfor}}